# Why am I getting 'Invalid XML' when calling jQuery.parseXML in Node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js, xml-deserialization

When I do this:

```
require('jquery').parseXML('<foo>bar</foo>');
```

I get this:

```
Invalid XML: <foo>bar</foo>
```

Calling the equivalent in the browser (`$.parseXML('<foo>bar</foo>')`) seems to work fine.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using Node.js v0.6.6 and jquery v1.6.3 installed via NPM.

If there is a more appropriate way to parse a string into an XML document in Node.js, I would be interested in learning that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [node-xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) if you want to have it converted to javascript object.

Comment: Thanks!  This might be useful for my application.  Is there a way to do CSS-style selectors on JavaScript objects?

Comment: No, as far as I know. I'm not sure if it makes sense to have something like that at all.

Comment: node-xml2js worked for my application.  Getting at the data I was interested in from the JavaScript object was much simpler than what I was doing before (jQuery selectors on an XML object).  Thanks again!